# PaperClip is not executing validates_attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

PaperClip is not executing validates_attachment when the line:

```
after_post_process :extract_text
```

is active. If I comment it out validates_attachment is executed as desired. The documentation states that the validations are done before post_process.

I'm using Rails 4.2.3, Ruby 2.0, PaperClip 4.3.0 .

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }

  has_attached_file :fdoc,
                    :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"

  validates_attachment :fdoc,
                       :presence => true,
                       :content_type => { :content_type => "application/pdf" },
                       :file_name => { :matches => [/pdf\Z/] }

  after_post_process :extract_text

  def extract_text

    reader = PDF::Reader.new(fdoc.queued_for_write[:original].path)

    full_text = ""
    reader.pages.each do |page|
      full_text << page.text
    end    

    self.text = full_text
  end

end
```

**UPDATE:**

I added a begin/rescue block to prevent my extract_text function from crashing if the upload is not a PDF and the validations are executed properly.

Therefore the documentation is not correct. Validations are executed after the post_process events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to paperclip README.md after_post_process won't fire if self.valid? is false. However I found that after_post_process is called no matter what so I added:

```
after_post_process :my_method

def my_method
  if self.valid?
     # execute code
  end
end
```